# Is any difference in calling function in form_load and button_click?

Tags: c#, lifecycle

I have done a window form application by showing the data to the datagridview. But there was some problem when the data showing in the datagridview.

The Function :

```
private void MySQL_ToDatagridview4()
{
    dataGridView3.Columns.Clear();
    mcon.Close();
    mcon.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    string sqlSelectAll = "SELECT Item_Name,Item_Pic from stockitem ORDER BY Main_Category_ID ASC, Item_Name ASC";
    MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, mcon);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    MyDA.Fill(table);
    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
    bSource.DataSource = table;
    this.dataGridView3.DataSource = bSource;
    DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    imageColumn.HeaderText = "Pic";
    dataGridView3.Columns.Insert(0, imageColumn);
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            String pic = table.Rows[i]["Item_Pic"].ToString();
            Byte[] bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage(pic));
            System.IO.MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmapData);
            def = new Bitmap((Bitmap)Image.FromStream(streamBitmap));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace);
        }
        dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = def;
    }
    dataGridView3.Columns.Remove("Item_Pic");
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
    {
        row.Height = 110;
    }
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView3.Columns)
    {
        col.Width = 110;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        dataGridView3.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        dataGridView3.AutoResizeColumns();
        dataGridView3.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8F, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
    mcon.Close();
}
```

Called in Form_Load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySQL_ToDatagridview4();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Then when I click the button

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySQL_ToDatagridview4();
}
```

Result:

[image: Image2]

Why the result is so different? It's calling the same function.

Comment: Context is everything. The `Load` event is raised just once, as the `Form` object is being initialized. Clearly, something that the view depends on has not been fully initialized yet when the `Load` event is raised. What that is, I can't say. You haven't included a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem in your question. Please improve the question if you want a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. there is a difference. Refer [Form events life cycle](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/windows-forms-events-lifecycle/). Form Load event occurs before a form is shown for the first time.

Try using Form shown event. It might help you, make sure UI thread is smooth (I mean to say avoid using Message box kind of stuff until page is fully shown and painted).

Comment: But why is it failing in case of form_Load event? Is it something specific to datagrid view control or the bit map pictures getting loaded into the grid view. I so often do setting datasource of controls like dropdownlist etc and it just works in form_load event as well.